# jquery menu and document event handling

Tags: jquery, events, menu

I have a popup menu like the inbox one on this site.

When I click it the submenu appears. Whne I click anywhere else in the document the menu should disappear.

The problem is when I try and click a link inside the menu it just triggers the document event handler. What is the solution for this is there a way to exclude certain dom elemments?

```
$('#account img').on('click', function() {

   if( $('.account-menu').hasClass('showing')) {
  $('.account-menu').fadeOut('200').removeClass('showing');
  return false;
 }
 else {
   $('.account-menu').fadeIn('200').addClass('showing');
   return false;
 }

});

$( document).on('click', function() {

   if( $('.account-menu').hasClass('showing')) {
  $('.account-menu').fadeOut('200').removeClass('showing');
  return false;
}
});
```

the html

```
<div id="account" class="large-3 show-for-large-up columns centred text-center">        
 <img src="/html/img/icon-user.png" alt="icon-user" width="37"  height="37" />  
</div>
    <div class="account-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{path='LOGOUT'}">Logout</a> </li>
            <li>View Profile</li>
            <li>Edit Profile</li>
        </ul>
    <div class="top"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide your html?

Comment: `event.target` will be your friend on this. [http://api.jquery.com/event.target/](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document).on('click', function() {

   if( $('.account-menu').hasClass('showing')) {
  $('.account-menu').fadeOut('200').removeClass('showing');

}
});
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/VL2z2/2/)

Event bubbling occurs so we need to stop using stopPropagation

```
$('#account img').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
   if( $('.account-menu').hasClass('showing')) {
        $('.account-menu').fadeOut('200').removeClass('showing');

}
else {
        $('.account-menu').fadeIn('200').addClass('showing');

 }
}
```

Comment: because you write click function for document. In that document only you have that div and image so document only works children element not works . so we need put event stopProgation is must

Comment: All should be right in your code. just add event stopPropagation for children click

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the parent element of the clicked element `event.target` (or itself) is not your menu in the document click event handler.

jQuery reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/ , http://api.jquery.com/parents/ and http://api.jquery.com/addBack/

Code:

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).parents(".account-menu").addBack().length>0) {
        if ($('.account-menu').hasClass('showing')) {
            $('.account-menu').fadeOut('200').removeClass('showing');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/KWsx8/